# Multi-user feature (sharing a folder) with Dropbox Sync API

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an app on Android & iOS, say ABC. It stores and accesses SQLite database (.db file) which is local to user's device.

To provide sync among different devices, I implemented Dropbox Sync API so that data entered on one device gets reflected on other devices automatically. Of course, the user must have linked the app ABC to their Dropbox account on all devices. So, its the same Dropbox account on all devices.
The SQLite database gets stored in app folder (Dropbpx/Apps/ABC). I have taken permission for app folder only.

Now, I wish to implement multi-user feature with read/write permissions where users with different Dropbox accounts can access this app folder (Dropbpx/Apps/ABC). It seems app folders can't be shared. (When I try to share an app folder, it says 'An app folder can't be shared')

This [link](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=59728) says you need Full Dropbox permissions to create a shared folder, but Sync API doesn't support Full Dropbox permission.

Any clues how can I provide multi-user feature (sharing a folder, .db files) with Sync API?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked forum thread is still correct that the Sync API doesn't currently support the Full Dropbox permission. It's also correct that app folders are currently incompatible with shared folders (i.e., app folders can't be shared, or contain or be contained in shared folders.)

However, there is a new permission, called File Type, introduced after that thread, that the Sync API supports and can be used with shared folders. You can find more information about the different permissions here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions

Also, while .db isn't one of the standard extensions available in the File Type permission buckets, Dropbox API support can enable custom extensions as noted here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/support#custom-extensions

Comment: Ok, File type permission for .db seems to do the trick. Just dropped a mail to Dropbox. Hope they add a custom file type (.db) for my app.

Comment: Got a reply. Dropbox is willing to create .db File Type permission. This would solve the shared folder problem, but sharing would be limited to read/write both in free account. We can't give read only permission for a shared folder on a free account.